# Speeding up reading the url response in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, urllib

I have a piece of code that queries  a server that returns a big json object(elasticsearch, BTW), 
It takes a lot of time to read the results. parsing the json object is very fast.

```
tic = time.time()
req_resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout = 60)
toc=time.time()
a = toc-tic

tic = time.time()
json_str = req_resp.read()
toc=time.time()
b = toc-tic

tic = time.time()
resp = json.loads(json_str)
toc=time.time()
c = toc-tic

print 'Fetch %.1f Process %.1f, load Json %.1f' %(a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
Fetch 0.5 Process 3.5, load Json 0.0
```

It seems strange that this takes so much time, while loading the json is fast. What am I doing wrong? any way to do this faster?

FYI this is a query for 1000 documents in elasticsearch, returning a few string fields which are several words long.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: That's not strange at all. It shows that network (and server processing) are the bottleneck, which is to be expected.

Comment: Why don't you just query elastic search database directly? I'm not familiar with elastic search but I doubt that it runs via HTTP server?

Comment: Do you run this query only once or many times?

Comment: @korylprince, on the contrary, the urlopen() is the network part, no? the req_resp.read() is only a processing of the result, no?

Glaslos, I run this many times.

nacholibre, it does run through rest.

Comment: @eran no that is incorrect. The body is transferred in the read. I am not sure exactly what all goes in the urlopen, but I believe it is only the request.

Comment: If json reads in smaller chunks, json.load(req_resp) would be faster than going through the intermediate json_str.

Comment: @eran now I'm not so sure. In my tests, most of the time is tied up in ```a```. When you think about it, the request body is sent by the server whenever it feels like it. But I think what's happening for you is that the code gets to ```req_resp.read()``` before the server has sent everything (because it's so large) and thus a lot of time is spent in the read to get everything. That's the only explanation I can come up with. I would love for someone with real knowledge of the code to answer.

Comment: Last follow up. Doing ```print inspect.getsource(req_resp.read)``` you can see any response that is buffered is given, then ```socket.recv``` is used for the rest, basically confirming my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `socket` module relies on `_socket` which is written in C++ (I think?). Presumably there is an overhead transferring large amounts of data between C++ and Python. I also get an oddly large overhead with `.read()` thou I have not tried it with huge data sets so it wasn't bigger than the fetch time. I'm not sure there is any thing you can do apart from switching to a different language. I will do some more testing and get back to you if I find any thing else.